# Конкатенация числа и строки по условию

Tags: python, строки, pandas

У меня есть фрейм, в котором две колонки:

- Цена(int)
- промо.

В промо два вида значений: либо NaN, либо str. Не могу написать цикл, который пробегал бы по столбцу промо и выполнял следующее условие: если в промо str, то мы конкатенируем значение этой строки с ценой, а если NaN, то оставляем просто цену.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 3):

В первом приближении можно просто использовать `.str.cat`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'price': [100, 223, 344234, 3423], 'promo': [pd.NA, ' - со скидкой', ' - можно в кредит', pd.NA]})
df['price-promo'] = df.price.astype(str).str.cat(df.promo.fillna(''))
df
```

Вывод:

```
    price   promo             price-promo
0   100     <NA>              100
1   223     - со скидкой      223 - со скидкой
2   344234  - можно в кредит  344234 - можно в кредит
3   3423    <NA>              3423
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще построчный `.apply` (Спасибо CrazyElf за исходный df):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'price': [100, 223, 344234, 3423], 'promo': [pd.NA, ' - со скидкой', ' - можно в кредит', pd.NA]})
df['price-promo'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x[0]) + x[1] if not pd.isna(x[1]) else str(x[0]), axis=1)
print(df))
```